# Has Sergei Lukyanenko revealed something about his political opinions since 2012?

Tags: russian-federation

Has [Sergei Lukyanenko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergei_Lukyanenko) (Russian science fiction and fantasy author) made any statement or given a public interview about his political opinions after the article [I Will Vote For Putin](http://akarlin.com/2012/01/sergey-lukyanenko-vote-for-putin/) he wrote in 2012?

Primarily I am interested in his opinions on Russian politics, but not only that.

Motivation to ask: In his books, politics is often mentioned and the article surprised me a lot, and I am interested in how his views changed since 2012.

Comment: Before this is voted off, could you please tell me what can I improve? Or if you consider off-topic (I read the Help and thought it is ok, but who knows), is there some other SE to ask this?

Comment: The question appears reasonable. Have you researched it? There are links on Wikipedia (en) about opposition to the Ukrainian government, and support for the annexation of Crimea (2015). But all the sources are in Russian. Our Russian users may be able to supply more details.

Comment: @JamesK Yes, I made research, but I didn't find anything in English, that is right. (only the old article mentioned in the question)

Comment: I don't know IRL answer, but his books reveal author's viewpoint as being strong Russian nationalism and exceptionalism, general soft disdain for the West in general and USA in particular (including rather unflattering references to Obama), **very** strong anti-Ukrainian views; and a somewhat fuzzy sociopolitical philosophy (under a microscope, everyone is equally unflattering and gray and nobody's a purely Good).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about the political beliefs of an obscure writer and is thus of little relevance to the vast majority of visitors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while this question is about an opinion of a popular science fiction writer, it's not clear to me that his opinion has any political significance. This site exists to help people to better understand inner workings of governments. As such, even if the author himself were answering the question, his *opinion* would not be appropriate for the site.Opinions of what a government (any government) ought to be,rather than what it is, are off topic.

Comment: @JonathanReez While I am not entirely sure that it is on topic. It is a broader question if asking about political views of one person is on topic. But I definitely don't think, that discussing obscurity of anybody is appropriate in the closing process.

Comment: @TGar in any case the opinions of non-political figures are off topic here

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact definition is, but Lukyanenko definitely doesn't fit it.

Comment: @JonathanReez I suppose that If we want to understand why people in Russia vote as they vote, we should not disregard the influence that popular authors like Lukyanenko have upon the public opinion through his books and films. The values he instills definitely affect the people's choices.

Comment: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3753/when-is-question-about-concrete-persons-political-views-off-topic

Comment: @JonathanReez while I agree that Lukyanenko's opinions are off topic for the site (although I am on the fence about it) because the site aims to explore inner workings of governments, your reasons might be slightly skewed.  You believe that the author is obscure.  He is not.  He is *highly* influential.  A few movies were produced based on his novels.  One of them was (for a time) available, with English subtitles, on Netflix .  That puts that movie in a category of being one of the most influential movies to come out of Russia.  I don't know if that's enough to make his opinion "politics".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have not heard of his interviews or other public statements entirely devoted to political issues, but his opinions can be seen from statements that occasionally slip out in his speeches on other topics. It seems that he believes, or at least wants the reader to think that he believes, that the Western world is hostile to Russia, and that it inspires and encourages the Russian opposition. He also approves of the official Russian policy towards Ukraine. However, he shies away from answering questions whether the current policy of Putin and Russian government is in the interests of people.

Below are some of Lukyanenko's statements (in shortened translation)

> Our opposition does not advocate its own interests, but serves as a
>   tool for achieving other counties's goals. ... This opposition offers
>   us to return to 1990s and lay under the authority of the USA.

(https://inosmi.ru/social/20181124/244082810.html)

> No one doubted Putin’s victory, but the activity of people has proved
>   to be higher than expected. The reason lies in the pressure that the
>   West is now putting on our country. In fact, an undeclared war is
>   being waged against us.

(https://antimaidan.ru/news/14952)

> Among Ukrainian authors there are people who accepted euromaidan with
>   an open mind.  Frankly, I have nothing to talk with them about. 
>   ...
>   These people supported euromaidan wholeheartedly. I see no sense and I
>   have no need to communicate with them.

(https://ukraina.ru/exclusive/20180716/1020626922.html)

> Travelling to Ukraine is the same thing that travelling to Nazy
>   Germany when death camps are operating there

(https://www.chel.kp.ru/daily/26676/3699432/)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, he did recently support Putin's aggression against Ukraine.

The statement in Russian:

[image]

> Bandits, armed with Nazi ideology, have been killing our compatriots
> for eight years, killing women, the elderly and children in the
> Donbass.
>
> For three years in a row, we have been gathering in front-line Donetsk
> at the international literary forum "Stars over Donbass". We see with
> our own eyes what Nazism is in the 21st century - broken houses,
> destroyed neighborhoods, graves of Donbass residents who died from the
> hands of Ukrainian punishers. We wipe away tears, looking at the names
> of the children in the Avenue of Angels.
>
> Forget? Never.
>
> Forgive? Impossible.
>
> In a difficult time of testing, when an aggressive information war
> began, we cannot stand aside. With us are millions of our readers,
> including those who are now carrying out their military duty with arms
> in their hands.
>
> We support our army, which acts as clearly, professionally and
> selflessly as possible; We support its Supreme Commander-in-Chief,
> President of the Russian Federation Vladimir Vladimirovich Putin, who
> launched a special operation to denazify and demilitarize the state of
> Ukraine.
>
> Retribution will surely come to those who allowed the militarization
> of Ukraine. Without it, its return to a normal, creative life is
> impossible. And we have no doubt that it will come.

Source:
https://web.archive.org/web/20220309080738/https://vk.com/wall-204123332_317

Comment: Could you provide a google translate or a handmade translation? Most people on this side can't read Russian.

Comment: @quarague I added a translation.

Answer (score 2):

He signed some letters in support of Russian agression, one is in @TGar's answer. [**Here is**](https://lgz.ru/article/-8-6822-23-02-2022/kto-khochet-zhertv/) another one. Interestingly, it is dated 23 February, so predates the invasion (but I am not sure it appeared on that date)...

Here is a slightly abridged translation (by Google, but quite good).

---

### **Who wants victims?**

*Appeal of Russian writers on the special operation of our army in the Donbass and on the territory of Ukraine.*

*By publishing this appeal, LG [Literaturnaya gazeta] emphasizes that in the entire polar spectrum of opinions that exist in the current media field, only one thing is undeniable and important: an early end to the bloodshed and suffering of civilians.*

The special military operation currently taking place in the Donbass and parts of Ukraine has long been brewing. The West did not stop trying to somehow hurt Russia, denigrate it and eventually dismember it. There is numerous evidence of this: from the declassified NATO military plans to destroy Russia and the constant heaps of lies by American television channels to the physical elimination of people in Ukraine who opposed the fascist ideology.

The anti-Russian hysteria has taken on a special scope since 2014, when the Crimeans freely and almost unanimously decided to join Russia, and the Donbass did not want any more humiliation for speaking and thinking in Russian. And Russia supported these legitimate demands.

Our desire for dialogue, Russia's concerns about security issues were not heard. Discord was deliberately sown with the help of aggressive military actions, fake news, informational provocations and inspirations. For 8 years, we have been patiently persuading all parties to comply with the Minsk agreements, but the West gave Ukraine the unspoken approval to disrupt them.

The pitting of the Slavs among themselves is unacceptable. We Russians don't want to pit anyone against anyone! Russians don't start a war. Russians usually finish it. Russia's special military operation is aimed at bringing peace to Europe.

We love the Ukrainian people, we sing Ukrainian songs, we watch Ukrainian movies, we pray in the same churches. We have common thoughts, and a keen desire to finally breathe in the air of the already near, common spring for our peoples. We have great writers bound by the same spiritual zeal for happiness, freedom, peace, and man. Leo Tolstoy and Nikolai Gogol, Taras Shevchenko and Alexander Pushkin, Lesya Ukrainka and Anna Akhmatova. We have a myriad of common victories and achievements that no one can cross out.

[...]

And what would have happened if the military operation had not begun? If Bandera’s followers had continued their cannibalistic marches around Kiev, they would have killed Ukrainian journalists, the teachers of the Russian language would have been imprisoned, the atrocities of those who burned people alive in Odessa, adopting the tactics of the Nazis, would have hung over Russia dirty Bandera atomic bomb!

So who wants victims? Our troops, who have not yet deliberately destroyed a single civilian? Or those who wage an ongoing linguistic war against the Russian language, as well as an information war against the Russian consciousness? The answer is clear. The West, which has embraced the Nazis, wants victims; they want the Banderlogs, who fraternize with NATO.

And what do we want? We want Ukraine to be sovereign and friendly, prosperous and free. But we don't want it to be ruled by the Nazis.

[...]

Peace be with you, Ukraine! Peace be with you, Russia and Belarus! We are from the same source, and this source of primordial Russia will feed both us and the peoples close to us in spirit, always!